# Javascript find() Can't Select Input Checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML structure :

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="checkbox-cod">
    <label class="non-escrow">
        <input type="checkbox" name="payment_method[COD]" value="1"> COD
    </label>
</div>
```

and I have this javascript (not jQuery) to select and check the input checkbox :

```
var kkCod = document.getElementById('checkbox-cod');
kkCod.find('input').checked = true;
```

but the selector is wrong. it can't select the input and give checked value. how to use `find()` properly in this case? thank you.

Comment: `.find()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method - don't you get an error in your browser's dev tools console that `.find()` is not defined?. Try `.querySelector()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe `find()` is a native method of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) but rather a [jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

You can however use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) like this:

```
kkCod.querySelector('input').checked = true;
```

Comment: it works, bro. thanks a lot! I just knew that javascript doesn't support find().

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can use `document.querySelector('#checkbox-cod')`  instead of `getElementById` .

As an alternative to jQuery find(), you can chain a call to querySelector like :

```
 document.querySelector('#checkbox-cod').querySelector('input').setAttribute('checked',true)
```